# Regex always matching 0 if possible when using the '?' quantifier?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm doing a regex pattern that attempts to get the server name from the following string:

```
/SERVER "\"TEST_SERVER\""
```

Sometimes the quotes and backslashes are omitted, so that the string just looks like:

```
/SERVER TEST_SERVER
```

In both cases I just want to match `TEST_SERVER`.
My pattern looks like this:

```
(?<=/SERVER ("\\")?)\S+(?=(\\"")?)
```

But this just matches the entire string `"\"TEST_SERVER\""` when there's quotes and backslashes in it. What am I doing wrong here?

I'm doing this in C#, here's my code:

```
string input2 = "/SERVER \"\\\"TEST_SERV\\\"\"";
string pattern = @"(?<=/SERVER (""\\"")?)\S+(?=(\\"""")?)";
Console.WriteLine("pattern=" + pattern);
Console.WriteLine("input=" + input2);

Regex regEx = new Regex(pattern);
MatchCollection matches = regEx.Matches(input2);
foreach (var match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.ToString());
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: which lang are you running?

Comment: I'm using C#, I've included the code I'm using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below regex to match the string `TEST_SERVER`,

```
(?<=\/SERVER\s*(?:["\\]+)?)\w+(?=(?:[\\"]+|$))
```

C# code would be,

```
String input = @"/SERVER ""\""TEST_SERVER\""""";
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"(?<=\/SERVER\s*(?:[""\\]+)?)\w+(?=(?:[\\""]+|$))");
foreach (Match m in rgx.Matches(input))
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[0].Value);
```

[IDEONE 1](http://ideone.com/W15aLs)
[IDEONE 2](http://ideone.com/LNEqB9)

Comment: Thanks, this works, what does the ?: do in (?:["\\]+)?

Comment: `(?:)` called non-capturing groups. It do a matching operation only and it won't capture anything. `[\\"]+` means match one or more `\` or `"` symbols.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following:

```
string input1 = @"/SERVER TEST_SERVER";
string input2 = @"/SERVER ""\""TEST_SERVER\""""";

string pattern = @"^/SERVER (""\\"")?(?<NAME>.+?)(\\"""")?$";

var regEx = new Regex(pattern);

Console.WriteLine(regEx.Match(input1).Groups["NAME"].Value);
Console.WriteLine(regEx.Match(input2).Groups["NAME"].Value);
```